# How do you loop through your current directory and store files in an array? Bash shell script

Tags: c++, arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

I am rather new to programming, and completely new to BASH. As described in the title, I am trying to loop through the current directory and store the files ending with .cpp into an array. I also am trying to create a second array which replaces the ".cpp" suffix with ".o" Whenever I try to compile I get "syntax error in conditional statement"

```
x=0
cwd=$(pwd)
for i in $cwd; do
  if [[ $i == *.cpp]]
  then
    cppfield[$x] = $i
    ofield[$x] = field[$x] | sed s/.cpp/.o/
    x=$((count+1))
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
shopt -s nullglob # In case there are no matches
for i in *.cpp; do
    ...
done
```

In your code, you're just setting `i` to `$cwd`, not the files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your purpose of doing this. But if you just want to generate file name that replaces .cpp with .o, it can be done in a much easier way

```
for f in *.cpp
do
    echo ${f/.cpp/.o}
done
```

Comment: I'd use `"${f%.cpp}.o"` -- with the "%" (meaning "remove this from the end") instead of "/" (meaning replace the first occurrence of) in case the filename contains ".cpp" somewhere other than the end, and double-quotes in case it contains spaces or other shell metacharacters.